# how to get camera width in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Problem**

I have a spawn manager written in c# which spawns my game object, i use screen.width, to set the maximum screen with and -screen.width to set the minimum screen width for the spawning, but my game object spawns way off the screen.

I am using a portrait camera 2:3 instead of free aspect as my camera view, as i want my game to be in portrait mode

how do i make my game object spawn within the camera widths(max and min)?

**my code**

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxBalloons = 100;
    public GameObject balloon;
    public float horizontalMin = -Screen.width;
    public float horizontalMax = Screen.width;
    public float verticalMin = -5.0f;
    public float verticalMax = 1.0f;


    private Vector2 originPosition;


    void Start () {

        originPosition = transform.position;
        Spawn ();

    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxBalloons; i++)
        {
            Vector2 randomPosition = originPosition + new Vector2 (Random.Range(horizontalMin, horizontalMax), Random.Range (verticalMin, verticalMax));

            Instantiate(balloon, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            originPosition = randomPosition;
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**
I changed

```
Vector2 randomPosition = originPosition + new Vector2 (Random.Range(horizontalMin, horizontalMax), Random.Range (verticalMin, verticalMax));
```

To

```
Vector2 randomPosition =Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (originPosition + new Vector2 (Random.Range(horizontalMin, horizontalMax), Random.Range (verticalMin, verticalMax)));
```

Still did not work as it should

Comment: With the use of your new edit (Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint). The camera width is a total of its size, so using a negative value should give you twice the area you are looking for. Maybe changing your horizontalMin = -Screen.width/2 and your horizontalMax to Screen.width/2  ?

Comment: This did not work too

Answer (score 0):

A position on your screen with a X smaller than 0 will be always out of your screen. The bottom left corner of your screen is the origin of your the coordinate (x: 0, y: 0)

But here I think you mingled 2 kinds of positions. The position on your screen, is not the same position in the world space of your scene. It depends where the camera is rendering.
The position on the bottom left corner of your screen will not be x:0 y:0 in the world space.

To achieve what you are looking for you need to transform the position on the left and the right of your camera into worldspace positions.

Use Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint to achieve that : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Comment: it doesn't make much difference

Comment: I added the change in my question

Comment: Please apply each part of my comment in your code. Here you still use -Screen.width so it's obviously out of your View. And don't use the originPosition in the sum, It probably kill the Math you do with ScreenToWorldPosition. Try to Debug.Draw the position to see if you are in the good way, and if not why.